# Spring AMQP RPC consumer how to determinated if the publisher channel has been closed

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc, spring-amqp

In RPC mode when the consumer receive and treat a message, is it possible to determinated whether the publisher is there or not waiting the response ?

For exemple if I stop the publisher process, the channel/the connection will be closed, so is it possible that the consumer verify this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; the publisher and consumer (by design) know nothing about each other; they are completely decoupled.

Comment: Thanks for your response.